# Android - how to repeat game

Tags: android

I'm an absolute beginner with Java/Android and for learning purposes, I try to develop a simple game, it's is a very simple number-guessing game :
1.the App generates a random number between 1 and 100
2.the player enters a numbers and the App tells the player if his number is too small, too big or correct.
3.if the entered number is correct then the App asks "do you want to repeat the game with the same number ?( YES/No )"
4.if player select "yes" then the same game should be repeated. "Same" game means that the same number should be used again for guessing (no new random number)
5.if player selects "no" then the game should repeat and generate new random number

Steps 1-3 are working
My problem are steps 4 and 5, so basically my problem consists of repeating the game

My my code:

```
public class frm_main extends ActionBarActivity {

private int     iGuessThisNumber;  //random number.
public  Context myContext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frm_main_layout);

    myContext = this;                                                               
    final TextView lblMeldung   = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.lblMeldung));     
    final EditText txtMyNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMyNumber);      

    //***********************************************************************************************************
    //   generate number that player must guess
    iGuessThisNumber = classCommonCode._generateRandomNumber(100);

    //***********************************************************************************************************
    //    check for DONE  Click in numeric softkeyboard
    txtMyNumber.setOnEditorActionListener(  new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()   
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView myTextView, int action, KeyEvent arg2event)
            {

                if (action == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
                //DONE was clicked - so player has entered his number
                {
                    //read number softkeyboard into integer
                    int iPlayerNumber; 
                    iPlayerNumber = Integer.parseInt(myTextView.getText().toString());

                    //compare player's number with random number and inform player about result (too big, too small, correct)
                    if (iPlayerNumber > iGuessThisNumber) {
                        lblMeldung.setText("Your number " + iPlayerNumber + " is too big");
                    }
                    if (iPlayerNumber < iGuessThisNumber) {
                        lblMeldung.setText("Your number " + iPlayerNumber + " is too small");
                    }
                    if (iPlayerNumber == iGuessThisNumber) {
                        lblMeldung.setText("Your number is CORRECT");

                        //ask if game should be repeated using the same number:
                        boolean bRepeatGameWithSameNumber; 
                        bRepeatGameWithSameNumber = classCommonCode._Ask("Do you want to repeat this game using teh same number?")
                        //so here is my problem:
                        /*
                        if (bRepeatGameWithSameNumber)
                        {what to do in this case ?}
                        else
                        {what to do in this case ?}
                        */

                    }

                    //clear numeric softkeyboard for next game
                    myTextView.setText("");

                    return true;// if return true the softkeyboard is not closed
                }

                return false;  //Return true if you have consumed the action (DONE Buttonon was clicked, else false.
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (bRepeatGameWithSameNumber)
   { // just reset your views to what should they display at beginning }
else 
   { iGuessThisNumber = classCommonCode._generateRandomNumber(100);
     // reset your views to what should they display at beginning }
```